# Calculated value (aggregation) displays in technical format

Tags: django

After calculating field in model I want to display this field in my template

model:

```
  def _get_total(self):
            from inventory.models import Inventory
            from purchase.models import POproduct
            from sales.models import SOproduct
        #    "Returns the total"

            return Inventory.objects.filter(warehouse_Bin__material_UOM__UOM__material=self.id ).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))  
            #- SOproduct.objects.filter(product__material=self.id).aggregate(Sum('quantity')) 
    #POproduct.objects.filter(Product__material=self.id).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))

    total = property(_get_total)
```

template:

```
<div> <b>total on hand:</b> {{ data.material.total }}</div>
```

However template displayed value in this format instead of plain numeric value

> total on hand: {'quantity__sum': Decimal('97.00000')}

I was trying to add parameter , output_field = models.DecimalField() to my sum function but getting an error I do not understand

> 'DecimalField' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression

'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the result set from the method which is a dict, try returning just the Decimal value:

```
quantity = Inventory.objects.filter(warehouse_Bin__material_UOM__UOM__material=self.id ).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))
return quantity['quantity__sum']
```